# How to fetch data from azure documentdb faster

Tags: python, sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to implement this example:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-python/blob/master/samples/DatabaseManagement/Program.py

To fetch data from azure documentdb and do some visualization. However, I would like to use a query on the line where it says #error here instead.

```
def read_database(client, id):
    print('3. Read a database by id')

    try:

       db = next((data for data in client.ReadDatabases() if data['id'] == database_id))
       coll = next((coll for coll in client.ReadCollections(db['_self']) if coll['id'] == database_collection))
       return list(itertools.islice(client.ReadDocuments(coll['_self']), 0, 100, 1))

    except errors.DocumentDBError as e:
        if e.status_code == 404:
            print('A Database with id \'{0}\' does not exist'.format(id))
        else:
            raise errors.HTTPFailure(e.status_code)
```

The fetching is really slow when I want to get >10k items, how can I improve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any error when executing the query? If so then please edit your question and include the error information. Also tell us if your collection is partitioned or not.

Comment: Hi, any progress now?

Answer (score 0):

You can't query documents directly through database entity.

The parameters of the ReadDocuments() method used in your code should be collection link and query options.

```
def ReadDocuments(self, collection_link, feed_options=None):
    """Reads all documents in a collection.

    :Parameters:
        - `collection_link`: str, the link to the document collection.
        - `feed_options`: dict

    :Returns:
        query_iterable.QueryIterable

    """
    if feed_options is None:
        feed_options = {}

    return self.QueryDocuments(collection_link, None, feed_options)
```

So, you could modify your code as below:

```
# Initialize the Python DocumentDB client
client = document_client.DocumentClient(config['ENDPOINT'], {'masterKey': config['MASTERKEY']})

db = "db"
coll = "coll"

try:
    database_link = 'dbs/' + db
    database = client.ReadDatabase(database_link)

    collection_link = 'dbs/' + db + "/colls/" + coll
    collection = client.ReadCollection(collection_link)

    # options = {}
    # options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
    # options['partitionKey'] = 'jay'
    docs = client.ReadDocuments(collection_link)
    print(list(docs))

except errors.DocumentDBError as e:
    if e.status_code == 404:
        print('A Database with id \'{0}\' does not exist'.format(id))
    else:
        raise errors.HTTPFailure(e.status_code)
```

If you want to query partition of your collection, please add the snippet of code which are commented in the above code.

```
   options = {}
   options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
   options['partitionKey'] = 'jay'
```

---

It seems that your issue is focused on Azure Cosmos DB query performance.

You could refer to the following points to improve query performance.

***Partitioning***

You could set partition keys in your database and query with a filter clause on a single partition key so that it needs lower latency and consumes lower RUs.

***Throughput***

You could set the throughput a bit larger so that Azure Cosmos DB performance in unit time will be greatly improved. Of course, this will lead to higher costs.

***Indexing Policy***

The use of indexing paths can offer improved performance and lower latency.

For more details, I recommend that you refer to the [official performance documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The thing is I can fetch the items from db, I read db with and coll before and return this:
return list(itertools.islice(client.ReadDocuments(coll['_self']), 0, 100, 1))

And it works well. However, it's really slow when the number of items goes up to 10k-100k. My question was how can I improve this?
Sorry, but I updated the question little bit

Comment: I will try these tips and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: @kai ok. Any concern please let me know.